# How to check only Wifi data usage in Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, network-traffic

Is there an API or example available where i can check only Wifi data usage? 
This is available in ICS onwards devices under settings. But how to do it through it. I want to get some ideas on that front.

Another thing to check here is that i only want to monitor the data usage if i am connected to 1 particular wifi network only, i guess that would not be a problem if i am able to get the data usage for Wifi?

Please see i am also aware of TrafficStats API but that does not solve my purpose.

Comment: Can anyone provide some inputs on this?

Comment: Are you looking to do this for your overall Wifi usage? Or Wifi usage for one particular app?

Comment: This will be for overall wifi usage. Any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `TrafficStats` APIs in this way to get Wifi usage:

```
int mobileTx = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
int mobileRx = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
int wifiTx = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mobileTx;
int wifiRx = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mobileRx;
```

This will return the total amount of Wifi data usage since the previous device boot.